# Getting around GWT Same Origin Policy

Tags: gwt

I am trying to implement the work around suggested on this link
http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/how_to_do_cross_domain
My existing Servlet on my server looks like

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ContactsServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet  implements ContactsService   
{
 ...
```

How do I modify this to get the cross domain to work.  Do I need to make any changes on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the GWT Same Origin Policy - it is the browser itself! The browser won't normally allow any XHR call to go out to a server that isn't the same server the page was loaded from.

The link you mentioned lets your server act as a proxy - thats one way to let the client talk to another server. The steps they take (create a servlet that forwards requests, configure it to point at the other server you want to use) do not require changes to the client.

Another option is to use the [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) - a way for the *server* to specify that the browser is allowed to contact it, even across domains. The catch: not all browsers support it.